# php reload page when fatal error occurs

Tags: php, error-handling

I am trying to figure out how to refresh page when a fatal error occurs. Basically I am  accessing an image api and copying images to my server. I am also creating a thumbnail version of the photo each time. I will receive an error message every once in a while stating that my script has tried to allocate too much memory. Which I have spent countless hours trying to resolve, with some help from the nice people on this website. It would be perfect I could just reload the page automatically when that error occurs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that an out of memory will let you do anything (never tried) but you can define your own error handler perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Edit:

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
  echo "Oh no! Error: $errno, $errstr";
  exit("try sticking a meta redirect here once you get the echo appearing");
}

set_error_handling('myErrorHandler');
// Now write something that runs out of memory, see if handler catches it.
```

Comment: I was just on that page. The examples are beyond the scope of my comfortability. And I can't quite understand the documentation.

Comment: It isn't easy to read. I'll add a simple example to the answer

Comment: Thanks! Also, Do you know if I could use memory_get_peak_usage() to break the script at 'X' amount of bytes? like `if(memory_get_peak_usage() > $x) die(header('Location: http://www.example.com/'));`

Comment: Sorry, Just tested. I can. Any idea if that gets the peak memory used at the time of the function call or will that if statement be valid for code below it in the script?

Comment: Sorry mate, got no idea. Not done much with memory functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error there, it should be "set_error_handler" not "set_error_handling"

```
set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
```

Maybe something like this would help.

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
$refresh = '10';
$pathdirectory = "";
echo "Oh no! Error: $errno, $errstr";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"$refresh;url=$pathdirectory\" />";
}

set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
```

Answer (score 0):

**put this code on start of page for register shutdown event (only support on PHP 5.2+)**

code detail:
when ever any fatal or other error will crash or shutdown your php page then this event will call and automatic refresh current page after X($errorRefreshSecs) secs**

```
<?php
function shutDownFunction() { 
$error = error_get_last();
// fatal error, E_ERROR === 1
if ($error['type'] === E_ERROR) { 
//do your stuff     
echo "<font color='red'>Oh no! fatal Error: ".$error["message"]." at line number: ".$error["line"]."</font><br>";
$errorRefreshSecs="3";
echo "please auto refresh page after $errorRefreshSecs Secs and try again!<br>";
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $errorRefreshSecs;?>; URL=<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
<?php
}//if end  //if ($error['type'] === E_ERROR) {
}
register_shutdown_function('shutDownFunction');//(only support on PHP 5.2+)
?>
```